# Converting input time 00 00 AM to DATETIME for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How can convert my time received from my $_GET variables as two digit values from a menu example:

```
$hours = 04;
$minutes = 45;
$ampm = 'PM';
```

into the correct format to insert into a DATETIME field in MySql

Comment: What date do you want it to have? A DATETIME has both a date and a time - do you want it to have the current day's date?

Comment: I want it to have a user entered time. For a schedule. Maybe I should use something other than DATETIME in MySQL?

Comment: Why not the appropriately named `TIME` type?

Comment: Well as I am going to be using this for scheduling the date values may come into play later. Say when I want to quickly query the # of days worked that week or such.

Comment: As I said, `DATETIME` has a date and a time component. If you need both, use it. If you don't, use either a `DATE` or `TIME` field. Remember, though, if someone's entering a time at 12:01 AM, they may be entering data for the previous day - depending on your use case, you *may* want to allow the user to enter date values as well as time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `DATETIME` to receive that time on the *current* date, this'll work:

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$hours}:{$minutes} {$ampm}"));
```